# Android - Custom View - Extending EditText with Views on Top

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-custom-view, butterknife

I'm trying to figure out a good solution on how to extend EditText to allow me to have other Views layered on top. I am trying to make a custom View that is an EditText that has a TextView on top to display the number of characters, and an ImageView on top for a clear button.

Currently, I have it working with extending FrameLayout, but that doesn't give me the control/flexibility that I am looking for. Such as I can't use ButterKnife's @OnTextChanged as it expects a TextView, and I don't have direct access to any XML attributes of the EditText unless I pass them through.

Thanks for your time.

ClearableEditText.java

```
public class ClearableEditText extends FrameLayout {

    public ClearableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    protected void init() {
        View inflate = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.clearable_edit_text, this);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, inflate);
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

R.layout.clearable_edit_text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/clearable_edit"
        style="@style/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/clearable_clear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/button_clear"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        tools:visibility="visible" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clearable_count"
        style="@style/edit_text_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        tools:text="1200" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can't same functionality be achieved by just using this layout and displaying numbers in text view as you type in edit text? Same thing for clearing the edit text. It seems to me that ButterKnife usage here is alitttle bit of an overkill. So is creating custom view for functionality that can be arranged otherwise. If I am missing something, would like to understand the reason for going the long way.

Comment: I used to have it within the layout using <include> but the problem is this functionality was all over my application. I'm trying to reproduce all the extra code for handling the counter / clearing by making it into one clean custom View.

Answer (score 1):

I find it simpler in these situations to use an empty layout in the xml which I later fill on runtime with whatever elements I want. example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView ..... />
    <Button........./>
    .
    .
    .
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

and in the activity

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
MyComplexView myComplexView = new MyComplexView(inflater, container);
```

where MyComplexView:

```
    public static class MyComplexView{

        LinearLayout container;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        TextView textView ;
        ImageView img;
        EditText editText;

        public MyComplexView(LinearLayout container,LayoutInflater inflater ){
            this.container = container;
            this.inflater = inflater;
            View v = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
            container.addView(v);
            textView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
            img = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imgaviev);
            editText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
            // assign whatever text change listeners or on click listeners you want
        }

        public void makeEditTextMultiline(boolean flag){
            if(flag){    
                edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE); 
            }
            else{
                edittext.setSingleLine(true);
            }
        }
        public String getEditTextText(){
            return editText.getText().toString();
        }

    }
```

After that you can create all sorts of methods in the MyComplexView class to manipulate the object.

I think it's easier this way than extending the View class.

Comment: That's an interesting solution, but I don't think it'll work for what I'm trying to accomplish. I want to extend the EditText so I can directly modify it through code/xml. For example, if I wanted the EditText to be multiline in one Activity, but not in another, I'd need more than one layout, or a lot of code within that Activity with your method, instead of within the extending Class.

Comment: That's why I said that you can add all sorts of methods inside the MyComplexView class to manipulate the object. You just add a method like setEditTextMultine(boolean flag) where you make the EditText multiline or not

Comment: You can't extend the EditText to do what you're describing.. You must extend the View class and build your custom view from the start. which is a loooot more code than this.  Updated the answer. Now after the object creation you can make it multiline or not. There are extremely few things that you can't manipulate about the views programmaticaly